# Is a function call expression with a single non-type template parameter argument type-dependent?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, dependent-type, compiler-bug

Both clang 3.6 and gcc 5.0 require `typename` in the following example:

```
template<typename T>
struct B
{
    typedef int Type;
};

void f(int);

template<int n>
struct A
{
    typedef typename B<decltype(f(n))>::Type Type;
};
```

This is covered by the following wording in the C++11 standard:

> [temp.dep.type]/5
>
> A name is a *member of an unknown specialization* if it is
>
> - A qualified-id in which the nested-name-specifier names a dependent type that is not the current
>     instantiation.
>
> [temp.dep.type]/8
>
> A type is dependent if it is
>
> - a member of an unknown specialization,
> - a simple-template-id in which either the template name is a template parameter or any of the template
>     arguments is a dependent type or an expression that is type-dependent or value-dependent
> - denoted by `decltype(expression)`, where expression is type-dependent

This suggests `B<decltype(f(n))>::Type` is type-dependent only if `B<decltype(f(n))>` is type-dependent. Also that `B<decltype(f(n))>` is dependent only if `f(n)` is type-dependent.

> [temp.dep.expr]/1
>
> Except as described below, an expression is type-dependent if any subexpression is type-dependent.
>
> [temp.dep.expr]/3
>
> An id-expression is type-dependent if it contains
>
> - an identifier associated by name lookup with one or more declarations declared with a dependent type,
> - a template-id that is dependent,
> - a conversion-function-id that specifies a dependent type, or
> - a nested-name-specifier or a qualified-id that names a member of an unknown specialization;
>
> or if it names a static data member of the current instantiation that has type “array of unknown bound of
>   T” for some T

This suggests `f(n)` is type-dependent only if `n` is type-dependent, and that `n` is *not* type-dependent.

Am I missing something, or is this a compiler bug?

Comment: The same behaviour occurs when substituting `f(n)` with `*new int(n)` which is not type-dependent according to [temp.dep.expr]/3

Answer (score 2):

Your analysis is a little bit incomplete, but otherwise correct.

> When a *qualified-id* is intended to refer to a type that is not a
>   member of the current instantiation (14.6.2.1) and its
>   *nested-name-specifier* refers to a dependent type, it shall be prefixed by the keyword `typename`, forming a *typename-specifier*.

Clearly `B<…>::Type` cannot refer to a member of the current instantiation. So the question is whether `B<decltype(f(n))>` is a dependent type.

> A type is dependent if it is
>
> - […]
> - a member of an unknown specialization,
> - […]
> - a *simple-template-id* in which either the template name is a template parameter or any of the template arguments is a dependent
>     type or an expression that is type-dependent or value-dependent, or
> - denoted by `decltype(expression)`, where *expression* is type-dependent (14.6.2.2).

`f(n)` isn't type-dependent as no sub-expression is, hence `decltype(f(n))` isn't a dependent type.
Also, `decltype(...)` cannot be value-dependent as it isn't a constant expression<sup>1</sup> and no other paragraph in [temp.dep.constexpr] applies. Clearly `decltype(f(n))` isn't type-dependent either.
And least but not last, `B<decltype(f(n))>::Type` would be a member of an unknown specialization only if the template argument was a dependent type<sup>2</sup>, which we concluded it isn't.

So by my interpretation the compilers are incorrect and the `typename` keyword is not required.

---

<sup>1</sup> In fact, `decltype(…)` is not an expression at all.

<sup>2</sup> [temp.dep.type]/5:

> A name is a member of an unknown specialization if it is
>
> - A *qualified-id* **in which the *nested-name-specifier* names a dependent type** that is not the current instantiation.
> - A *qualified-id* in which the *nested-name-specifier* refers to the current instantiation, **the current instantiation has at least one
>     dependent base class**, and name lookup of the *qualified-id* does not
>     find any member of a class that is the current instantiation or a
>     non-dependent base class thereof.
> - An *id-expression* denoting the member in a class member access expression (5.2.5) in which either
>
>   - […]